Use VSCode EIDE plugin and Stm32CubeIde for development, and include C++ standard librarywill report error
I am using the EIDE plugin with STM32CubeIDE for development in VSCode, and I want to include the C++ standard library in my project. However, when I include C++ standard library headers in the VSCode editor, I get the following error:
"Detected include errors based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting.
and
Cannot open source file 'bits/c++config.h' (dependency of 'map') C/C++(1696)"
ometimes there is only the 2nd error.
I encountered this error when I write #include .
I have used macro like:
#ifdef _cppplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif

to deal cpp files.
This error directly affects code completion in VSCode, which negatively impacts development experience and efficiency. Despite this, I can still navigate to the header file by pressing F12, and the code that includes the C++ standard library can be successfully compiled and flashed in both EIDE and STM32CubeIDE environments.
The EIDE documentation mentions not to manually create or edit the c_cpp_properties.json file. Therefore, in the settings.json file, I have commented out all C_cpp-related configurations. One proposed solution suggested configuring the settings.json like this:
"C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"

This does solve the header file issue, but it introduces new problems, such as red underlines in the HAL library calls within the C++ environment. So, this solution is largely unusable.
I have tried to deal the setting.json file to solve this problem.
I also googled and use gpt.Of course, gpt is not enough good to deal the environment problem.
Therefore, I am asking if anyone has a solution to this issue while still using EIDE and STM32CubeIDE. I would greatly appreciate it.
English is not my native or primary language, so I apologize for any errors in my expression.

It seems I have identified the problem, but I am not sure of the specific solution. The issue lies in that the STM32CubeIDE project contains its own system includes, which include many standard library header files. However, when the CubeIDE project is imported into EIDE, these system includes are not fully imported. By using C/C++: Log Diagnostics, it can be seen that the printed system includes are not exactly the same as those in the STM32CubeIDE includes.

A temporary workaround is to manually add the missing include paths in EIDE after comparison. However, this does not address the root of the problem. The correct approach should involve properly configuring EIDE, which likely involves settings based on the warning files generated after importing into Eclipse.Since I am a beginner in embedded systems, I must have missed some configurations based on this file.
